# Is there a simple way to remove unrequired jars from 'libs' folder for Android project?

Tags: android, jar, dependencies

I'm working on Android app which uses 3rd-party library with dependencies. So i had to copy lot's of `jar` files as dependencies to `libs` folder. Is there any simple way to remove unneeded ones (i'm not sure which ones are unneeded actually)? I'm not using Gradle or Maven in this project and i'm using IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: The primary way that you are going to determine which ones are "unneeded" is by removing them and running your test suite.

Comment: Yes, that's the question: "which ones are unneeded"? It will take lot's of time to remove them one-by-one and try to build the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the most simple and short way but i had to catch all `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` and `java.lang.VerifyError` exceptions.